Embrace Swift generics question, some\any keywoard. Protocol associatedtype with func
In wwdc2022 apple used static func to create model, which used later in type(of: )..
Here is a video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110352/
I wanna simplify example, but I got an error Member 'eat' cannot be used on value of type 'any QAnimal'; consider using a generic constraint instead. How to fix this ?
protocol QAnimalFeed {}
protocol QAnimal {
    associatedtype Feed: QAnimalFeed
    func eat(_ food: Feed)
}

class Cat {}
extension Cat: QAnimal {
    struct Feed: QAnimalFeed {}
    func eat(_ food: Feed) {
        print("cat eating")
    }
}

class Doge {}
extension Doge: QAnimal {
    struct Feed: QAnimalFeed {}
    func eat(_ food: Feed) {
        print("dog eating")
    }
}

func main() {
    let food: [any QAnimalFeed] = [Doge.Feed(), Cat.Feed()]
    let cells: [any QAnimal] = [Cat(), Cat()]

    cells.enumerated().forEach { index, animal in
        animal.eat(food[index]) // Member 'eat' cannot be used on value of type 'any QAnimal'; consider using a generic constraint instead
    }
}

Original code by apple, retrieved from link video above. Unfortunatly stackoverlow insist to write more text, but I dont know what I should provide more to clarify my question =)
protocol AnimalFeed {
    associatedtype CropType: Crop where CropType.Feed == Self
    static func grow() -> CropType
}

protocol Crop {
    associatedtype Feed: AnimalFeed where Feed.CropType == Self
    func harvest() -> Feed
}

protocol Animal {
    associatedtype Feed: AnimalFeed
    func eat(_ food: Feed)
}

struct Farm {
    func feed(_ animal: some Animal) {
        let crop = type(of: animal).Feed.grow()
        let produce = crop.harvest()
        animal.eat(produce)
    }

    func feedAll(_ animals: [any Animal]) {
        for animal in animals {
            feed(animal)
        }
    }
}

struct Cow: Animal {
    func eat(_ food: Hay) {}
}

struct Hay: AnimalFeed {
    static func grow() -> Alfalfa {
        Alfalfa()
    }
}

struct Alfalfa: Crop {
    func harvest() -> Hay {
        Hay()
    }
}


what i should do in here?, what do you mean? Please ask a clear question describing your issue.

@JoakimDanielson Thanks for reply, sir. I have updated my question, add an error description in func main() method. Can you check this in ur free time? Provide me more information if u dont understand my issue.

Basically, what the error message is telling you is: Do not make an array whose element is typed as a protocol. That's almost always a mistake (as here). You can only apply feed to an object whose type conforms to QAnimal; you cannot apply it an object whose type is QAnimal. That is why the error message suggests using a generic constraint instead of a protocol type.

@matt Have you ever checked the apple example ? They are created model using static func grow() -> CropType in here let crop = type(of: animal).Feed.grow(). I just wanna go away from static func and wanna fill my own data outside.

Do not insult me; if you insult people who are trying to help you, no one will try to help you. Instead, listen to me. The Apple example does not have any arrays that are typed as a protocol. Their example compiles. Your example does have arrays typed as a protocol. Your example does not compile. I am explaining to you why your example does not compile. — Perhaps it will help if I give you a simpler example. Consider this code: var thing: (any QAnimal)!; var feed: QAnimalFeed!; thing.eat(feed). Don't worry about running it; just try to compile it. You can't. It's the same error. See?

@matt Sorry sir, eng is not my native language i dont wanna to insult u. I just found an answer in my question. If u curious about it check below. Thanks for replying, have a good day

Answer
extension QAnimal {
    func eat(any food: any QAnimalFeed) {
        if let food = food as? Self.Feed {
            eat(food)
        }
    }
}

And refactoring this
func main() {
    let food: [any QAnimalFeed] = [Doge.Feed(), Cat.Feed()]
    let cells: [any QAnimal] = [Doge(), Cat()]

    cells.enumerated().forEach { index, animal in
        let oneFood = food[index]
        animal.eat(any: oneFood)
    }
}

Hope this will help someone in the future.

Self.Feed Is redundant. Just Feed should suffice
